# Get the first instance of a field where it's not null from rows

Tags: theming, 8

I've got a view page, which is pulling together quite a few content types. All of these content types have a field called `field_image`, however some are not required and/or are missing.

I basically need to grab the first (latest - sorting by author date in my view settings) row, check if there's a `field_image`, if there is, we can just return that field, if not, repeat.

I thought about a few different ways of doing this, and I thought that I'd make it a Twig command for ease. My issue is that I can't seem to get the single field I'm looking for.

**My Twig function is currently:**

```
public function get_first_instance($field, $rows) {
  foreach($rows[0]['#rows'] as $row) {
    dump($row['#row']);
    exit;
  }
}
```

I'm running the Twig command from my `views-view--my-content-type--page.html.twig` template, passing a string, and `rows`.

I can see that the `field_image` is located in `_entity > #fields > field_image`, I'm just not sure how to reference this, or what function to use to load the entity?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it, makes sense now!**

```
public function get_first_instance($field, $rows) {

  foreach($rows[0]['#rows'] as $row) {
    $entity = $row['#row']->_entity;

    if($entity->hasField($field)) {
      $value = $entity->get($field)->getValue();

      if(! empty($value)) {
        return $value;
      }
    }
  }

  return dump('Field not found: '.$field);
}
```